# API Twitter 1.1 all stream

Tags: php, json, twitter

I need to get all the stream from twitter for a certain word.
In the 1.0 version I did something like:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=' . $words . '&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed
```

And got the return result into a json variable. But for the 1.1 version if I call the newest link I get nothing.

```
https://twitter.com/search?q=' . $words . '&src=typd
```

What's to be done?

Comment: 1.1 uses OAuth, API access requires authentication now. Heres a simple Twitter proxy. http://cherone.co.uk/blog/Twitter_Proxy or you can use the official API library's https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

Comment: Cand you give me an example?

Comment: Can you put that as an answer? I want to close this thread and this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has changed and it need authentication. So that is the solution.